# Hover fadeOut jQuery issue

Tags: jquery, hover

I have a page with a 3 images slider. If you hover the left part of the slider, an arrow showing the left direction appear and replace the mouse. And if you hover the right part of the slider, an arrow showing the right direction appear and replace the mouse. And also, those arrows appear and disappear fading in and out (that's why I'm using jQuery and not the css cursor property).

I did all that, but the problem is that when the mouse quit the slider *only from left to right bottom*, the arrows don't disappear until you move the mouse to another direction.

So here's my code, first the HTML part:

```
<div id="arrow-prev" class="arrow">
<img id="cursorimg_prev" src="style/arrow-left.png" />
</div>

<div id="arrow-next" class="arrow">
<img id="cursorimg_next" src="style/arrow-right.png" />
</div>
```

The CSS:

```
.arrow
{
height: 585px;
width: 750px;
position: absolute;
top: 0px;
}

#arrow-prev
{
left: 0px;
cursor: none;
width:50%;
}

#arrow-next
{
right: 0px;
cursor:none;
width:50%;
}

#cursorimg_prev,
#cursorimg_next
{
position: absolute;
display: none;
z-index: 99;
}
```

And the jQuery part:

```
$('#arrow-prev').mousemove(function(event) {
            var position = $('.slider_conteneur').position();
            var x = event.pageX - position.left - 0;
            var y = event.pageY - position.top - 0;
            $('#cursorimg_prev').css({ top: y+"px", left: x+"px" });
        });

        $('#arrow-prev').hover(function() {
            $('#cursorimg_prev').stop().fadeIn(100);
        }, function(){
            $('#cursorimg_prev').stop().fadeOut(100);
        });

        $('#arrow-next').mousemove(function(event) {
        var position = $('.slider_conteneur').position();
        var position2 = $('#arrow-next').position();

        var x = event.pageX - position.left - position2.left;
        var y = event.pageY - position.top - position2.top;
        $('#cursorimg_next').css({ top: y+"px", left: x+"px" });
        });

        $('#arrow-next').hover(function() {
            $('#cursorimg_next').stop().fadeIn(100);
        }, function(){
            $('#cursorimg_next').stop().fadeOut(100);
        });
```

Hope someone can help!

Comment: Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZEjQp/) for anyone trying to solve this.

Answer (score 1):

I think that your error is that you are looking using hover on the .arrow divs, those make out half the visible area each. and the hover effekt will be visible until your mouse leves the area of the divs

i changed some stuff(mostly css to adjust the size of the containers, this can be done in multiple ways) and uploaded it to jsfiddle(replacing the images that i don’t have with alt text but it should serve the same purpose), i also removed the mousemove events as they where causing a lot of errors.

I hope i understood your question correctly

http://jsfiddle.net/fESVm/

```
    .arrow
     {
     height: 585px;
     width: 28px;
     position: absolute;
     margin-right:182px;
     top: 0px;
     }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, I tried your solution but it doesn't work. I don't know if you have really understood what was the issue? The problem is that when the mouse leaves the slider from left to right/bottom, the arrow don't disappear.

Comment: Thanks again, but the code you linked is quite the same as mine, so there's still the same issue. I don't know if I understood what you wanted to do with the css, but I guess the problem is in the JavaScript.